# mysql shift rows at the bottom of the result set

Tags: mysql, rows, shift

I am trying to shift rows with value less than current date at the bottom of the result set. I've this query

```
SELECT 
r_id AS Id,
f_title AS Title,
f_desc AS Description,
f_upload_file AS File,
ABS(DAYOFYEAR(f_valid_date)- DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE())) AS Deadline,
f_added_on as 'Added On'
FROM t_documents
WHERE 
f_rec_status= TRUE
ORDER BY Deadline ASC
```

and it gives this result:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN Deadline IS NULL
               THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ASC, Deadline ASC
```

Comment: that work perfectly and i really appreciate your response it was quick. however looks like i am still into it ... 
actually what i want is to display results on top which are close to current date and at last which are expired ... 
it doesn't seem to be working as its mixing up with the months and years ...
any suggestions?